# Convert all headings to anchor links

Tags: javascript, jquery

All the h1 tags in my webpage contain a custom tool-tip and an anchor(which are added with jquery). The html looks like this:

```
<h1 id="heading1">
<span>
Intro
<div class="tooltip">
<i class="icon-decline">X</i>
<div class="tooltip-arrow"></div>
<div class="tooltip-inner">
<input type="text" readonly="readonly" value="http://someurl/somemore/#heading1">
</div>
</div>
<a href="http://someurl/somemore/#heading1" class="anchor"><i class="icon-chain-link">#</i>
</a>
</span>
</h1>
```

For smaller devices after hiding the tool-tip and the anchor I want convert the string within the h1 to an anchor link with the native link of the heading. I want something like this:

```
<h1 id="heading1">
<span>
<a href="http://someurl/somemore/#heading1">Intro</a>
<div class="tooltip">
<i class="icon-decline">X</i>
<div class="tooltip-arrow"></div>
<div class="tooltip-inner">
<input type="text" readonly="readonly" value="http://someurl/somemore/#heading1">
</div>
</div>
<a href="http://someurl/somemore/#heading1" class="anchor"><i class="icon-chain-link">#</i>
</a>
</span>
</h1>
```

Unfortunately until now I haven't found a way to target solely the text string and the jquery wrapInner() method, that I'm using, wraps all the the elements inside the h1. This is my code until now:

```
//the function to hide the tooltip, the anchor and convert the h1 to link 
function makeResponsive(){
if ($(window).width() < 780) {
    $('h1').wrapInner('<a href="'+ this.href +'"></a>');
    $('div.tooltip').css('display', 'none');
    $('a.anchor').hide();

} else {
    $('a.anchor').show();
}
}

//run on document load and on window resize
$(document).ready(function () {

//on load
makeResponsive();

//on resize
$(window).resize(function(){
    makeResponsive();
});

});
```

Here is a [working example](https://jsfiddle.net/SharPei/hmyf4mp7/3/) with an additional h2 tag. **First problem:** I can't set the id from the h tag as location.hash **Second problem:** Want to convert only the text string of the h tag to a link

Comment: Could you provide a working example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is my solution:

```
      if ($(window).width() < 780) {
          $('h1 > span, h2 > span, h3 > span').each(function() {
          window.location.hash = this.parentElement.id;//set the local id as hash
          $(this).contents().eq(0).wrap('<a class="native" href="' + window.location.hash + '"></a>');
    });//get ONLY the text within the h tags and wrap it with a tags that have the local hash
```

In devices with `width` less than `780px` for each `span` within the `h` tags I set the hash equal to the `id` of their parent. Then i get the first content of the `span`, which is the `text` and wrap it with an `a` that has the complete URL of the location.

In devices with `width` more than `780px` I just find and unwrap the `a` tags that wrap the text.

```
} else {
    $('a.native').contents().unwrap();
  }
```

Here is a [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/SharPei/kb4no989/3/) with the complete code.

Answer (score 0):

If a tag contains an `id` attribute, you don't need an anchor for it.

If this page `http://www.example.com/page1.html` contains a tag like `<section id="general_information">`, all you need to link directly to that section is a link like `<a href="http://www.example.com/page1.html#general_information">...</a>`

Answer (score 0):

Following the example are you forgetting this part:

```
$('a.anchor').click(function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  var thistool = $(this).parent().find('div.tooltip');
  $('div.tooltip').not(thistool).hide();
  thistool.toggle();
  thistool.find('input').select();
});

$('.icon-decline').on('click', function() {
  $(this).parent().hide();
});

$('div.tooltip').on('click', function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
});

$(document).on('click', function() {
  $('div.tooltip').hide();
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/hmyf4mp7/4/